# ASP.Net MVC-5 Editor Templates, ViewData & placeholder (watermark) results in extraneous markup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates, viewdata

I have implemented an Editor Template for each of my input types which populate the css "placeholder" with the "Prompt" Display annotation from my models.

In the first instance I just added "placeholder"=ViewData.ModelMetaData.Watermark to ViewData and passed ViewData in to the TextBox() HtmlAttributes parameter as suggested in several posts on here and around. (Thanks to [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) in particular.)

However, this had the effect of adding "returnurl", "title" and several other ViewData properties to each and every input control.  Not very satisfactory.

I took a look at [this post](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) and was about to give it a try when I figured I would take that idea and create an array of strings that represent the Keys of the ViewData properties I don't want included in the input-markup and loop through the ViewData and only add those properties that aren't in that list.

This is my code for the String Editor Template (Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml):

```
@{
IDictionary<string, object> htmlAtts = new Dictionary<string, object>();
string[] varData = {"ReturnUrl", "Title"}; //there are more values in my actual code
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in ViewData)
{
    if (!varData.Contains(entry.Key)) {
        htmlAtts.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}
htmlAtts["placeholder"] = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark;
}
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAtts)
```

(BTW this code will be re-factored to keep it DRY)

It would have been nice if "placeholder" was implemented by the framework, or if there was a simple way of grabbing the HTML attributes at this point and adding the "placeholder" to those attributes only, without having to do this loop to exclude non-HTML-Attribute-ViewData.

Am I missing something?  Is there a better way of achieving what this solution has done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in my question, this is the code for the String Editor Template that solved the problem (Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml):

```
@{
IDictionary<string, object> htmlAtts = new Dictionary<string, object>();
string[] varData = {"ReturnUrl", "Title"}; //there are more values in my actual code
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in ViewData)
{
    if (!varData.Contains(entry.Key)) {
        htmlAtts.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
}
htmlAtts["placeholder"] = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark;
}
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAtts)
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you are trying to accomplish is to add the placeholder from the ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark, then your String Template can be as simple as follows:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

And your placeholder text can be set in the DataAnnotations of your View Model.

Comment: yes, but that loses all other html attributes set in razor markup, doesn't it?